# How to assign Windows media keys to functions in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript, media-player, audio-player

I've made a music player in Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Basic. I would now like to assign the keys in the top right hand corner to a function. On my keyboard, at least, the 'Home', 'Pg Up', 'Pg Down' and 'End' keys all have media keys on them (pause/play, stop, previous, forward). These are written in blue so, obviously, you need to press 'Fn' to use the alternative functions (instead of 'Home', press 'Fn' + 'Home'). Might not be the clearest of explanations but it's not exactly rocket science to understand what I want to do. I want to start a function when the user is holding 'Fn' and presses one of the buttons mentioned above.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Is your question about VB or VBScript? They're two different languages.

Comment: Is that 'Fn' key exist on your keyboard? I have not such key.

Comment: I am using VB and, yes, the 'Fn' key in the bottom left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trap the multimedia keys using the Keys.MediaXXX constants.  Here's an example of trapping those keys in a standard form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessKeyMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean
        Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
        If m.Msg = WM_KEYDOWN Then
            Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32
                Case Keys.MediaStop
                    Debug.Print("Stop")
                Case Keys.MediaPlayPause
                    Debug.Print("PlayPause")
                Case Keys.MediaNextTrack
                    Debug.Print("Next")
                Case Keys.MediaPreviousTrack
                    Debug.Print("Previous")
            End Select
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessKeyMessage(m)
    End Function

End Class
```

*This can also be done in the Form's KeyDown() event using `e.KeyData`.

EDIT:  Here's an example of using the Form's KeyDown() event.  Note that I enabled KeyPreview(); this would need to be done if there are any controls on the form that can receive focus:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyData
            Case Keys.MediaStop
                Debug.Print("Stop")
            Case Keys.MediaPlayPause
                Debug.Print("PlayPause")
            Case Keys.MediaNextTrack
                Debug.Print("Next")
            Case Keys.MediaPreviousTrack
                Debug.Print("Previous")
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This will only work when your form has FOCUS.  If you want to trap these keys when your form does NOT have focuse then you'd have to trap them with a low level keyboard hook (Google for WH_KEYBOARD_LL).

Comment: I'm not able to get it to work. Do I have to call the function through the KeyDown function of form 1?

Comment: I've I've just got to look into the WH_KEYBOARD_LL as mentioned above so it doesn't need focus, Thanks:)